# Mesh doesn't appear in object mode?

Tags: 3d-view

When i add mesh in my scene in object mode. It doesn't appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps in the Viewport Shading options (small down arrow button on the top right), the X ray might be enabled and at a value of 0?

Comment: not the problem X ray  is not enabled . but when i press tab and enable edit mode it appears when i back to object modes it desappeares again (sorry i am bad at English hope understand me )

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i uploaded it .

Comment: I don't see any link

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/qpMD7SqY/

Comment: in Cycles it works fine, in Eevee I can't say because doesn't work fine on my computer, I hope someone will tell

Comment: ok thank you for your reply !

Comment: I don't have your issue. Solid view looks OK. It can be graphic card issue, but I haven't heard it can happen in Solid view. How old hardware are you using?

Comment: my laptop is hp 8470 p .  graphic card is AMD Radeon HD 7570M